# Различные теги в инструменте разработчика и исходном коде

Tags: парсер, python-3.6

Пытаюсь спарсить данные с CMS-ки нашего интернет-магазина, чтобы автоматизировать проверку карточек товаров. Для этого мне нужно содержимое тега , а конкретнее - все span'ы в нем (дочка не первого уровня), судя по инструменту разработчика. Однако, через библиотеку BeatifulSoup4 Python'а выдает пустой список span'ов. В исходном коде страницы тег  имеется, однако необходимая информация содержится в одном из тегов . Подскажите, как спарсить необходимую информацию через bs4?

Comment: Вам необходимо указать, что конкретно вы не понимаете, приложить пример решения, на котором у вас ошибка появилась. На данный момент вопрос не соответствует правилам сообщества.

Comment: Если магазин ваш, то почему бы не выгрузить данные из БД?

Answer (score 0):

Простите за плохо сформулированный вопрос. С проблемой получилось разобраться: меня смутил javascript, который преобразует теги, и поэтому не получалось идентифицировать нужный. Как оказалось, надо лишь отключить js, и тогда все встает на свои места.

Не достаю (пока что) данные напрямую с базы, так как пытаюсь научиться парсить